# AWS Lambda with 10 different roles executing it. Can I get their tags?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

General question here.

I have a lambda function that has an assigned role. I also have 10 other roles in my AWS account that need to execute this function. Fine. I can assign those permissions in a policy that they can attach to their role.

My question is, I want to know more information inside my lambda function about the 10 different roles that is calling my main lambda function. Is it possible to get the tags of the roles that is trying to execute my function? If so, how

Comment: You have this info in context object of lambda, to be more specific you can see which arn cause function execution. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html

Comment: What do you mean by "10 other roles in my AWS account that need to execute this function"? There are two sets of permissions involved. First is the permission to `Invoke()` the function. Second is the IAM Role assigned to the function, which it uses to obtain permission to access AWS services when using an AWS SDK. Are these "10 roles" _invoking_ the function, or are you changing the IAM Role associated with the function each time?